# How to Remove Elements from PriorityQueue according to a Element Property?

Tags: java, search, priority-queue

I am try to set `Maximum Waiting Time` inside my `PQueue`. This  `Maximum Waiting Time` will check my `PQueue` automatically if there are any `links` are waiting more than `Maximum Waiting Time` to remove it. I did this changes to my code it is working but it is stopping exactly after removing the links. I want to remove all elements from my `PQueue` according to waiting time condition. Can you tell me what I am missing here ?

This is my class:

```
public class MyClass {

    public static PriorityQueue <LinkNodeLight> PQueue = new PriorityQueue <> (); 


    private static Set<String> DuplicationLinksHub = new LinkedHashSet <> ();         

    private static Integer IntraLinkCount = new Integer (0);                 
    private static Integer InterLinkCount = new Integer (0);                 
    private static Integer DuplicationLinksCount = new Integer (0);     
    private static Integer MaxWaitTime = new Integer (60000); // 1 M= 60000 MS


    @SuppressWarnings("null")
    LinkNode deque(){

        LinkNode link = null;
        synchronized (PQueue) {

            link = (LinkNode) PQueue.poll();
            if (link != null) {
                link.setDequeTime(new DateTime());
                if (link.isInterLinks())
                    synchronized (InterLinkCount) {
                        InterLinkCount--;
                        }
                else
                    synchronized (IntraLinkCount) {
                        IntraLinkCount--;
                        }
            }

            synchronized (PQueue) {
                if (link.waitingInQueue()>MaxWaitTime) {

                    link = (LinkNode) PQueue.remove();
                                    System.out.println("*********************************");
                                    System.out.println("This Link is Deopped: " + link);
                                    System.out.println("%%% MaX Waiting Time:" + (MaxWaitTime/60000)+"Min");

                                    System.out.println("*********************************");
                  }
            }
            return link;


        }
```

Comment: Haven't looked through all your code, but synchronizing on `InterLinkCount` or `IntraLinkCount` doesn't work. You keep changing what object those variables refer to, so different threads don't acquire the same locks.

Comment: @user2357112 this is not my whole project since it is a big program. This is a part of it. I can provide other procedures regarding the code if needed

Comment: A general comment: don't use `new Integer(n)`, instead use `Integer.valueOf(n)`. It is much more efficient.

Comment: Never synchronize on a mutable variable! `synchronized(IntraLinkCount){IntraLinkCount--;}` is *not* thread safe!

Comment: @Holger So what do you prefer instead of synchronized(IntraLinkCount){IntraLinkCount--;} How should I used it ?

Comment: [Tomas’ answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33375042/2711488) already contains an alternative.

Answer (score 3):

Your question is a bit opaque, but if I understand it correctly you want to check your `PriorityQueue` to see if there are items that have waited longer than a specific time.

Your usage of `synchronized` on the `IntraLinkCount` and `InterLinkCount` is, as has been mentioned already, a bit strange. There is a fairly unknown alternative, the atomic integer class `AtomicInteger` (in the package `java.util.concurrent.atomic`:

```
private static AtomicInteger IntraLinkCount = Integer.valueOf(0);
```

This will work as you want.

The second problem is that you use the `poll()` method. This will *remove* the top item from the queue. Maybe you want to use `peek()` instead, and then only use `remove()` if the returned link object satisfies `link.waitingInQueue() > MaxWaitTime`?

By the way, your queue will return items according to their "natural ordering". This means the `compareTo` method is used, and the "smallest" will be returned from the queue first. I think you might want to implement a custom `compareTo` that puts the *longest waiting* link first instead?

You could also [create your `PriorityQueue` with a custom `Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html#PriorityQueue-java.util.Comparator-) object instead.

Something like this:

```
public class MyClass {
    public static PriorityQueue<LinkNodeLight> PQueue = new PriorityQueue<>();

    private static AtomicInteger IntraLinkCount = new AtomicInteger(0);
    private static AtomicInteger InterLinkCount = new AtomicInteger(0);

    private static Integer MaxWaitTime = Integer.valueOf(60_000); // 1 M= 60000 MS

    LinkNode deque() {
        LinkNode link = null;

        synchronized (PQueue) {
            link = PQueue.peek();

            if (link != null) {
                link.setDequeTime(LocalDateTime.now());

                if (link.isInterLinks())
                    InterLinkCount.decrementAndGet();
                else
                    IntraLinkCount.decrementAndGet();

                if (link.waitingInQueue() > MaxWaitTime) {
                    link = PQueue.remove();

                    System.out.println("*********************************");
                    System.out.println("This Link is Deopped: " + link);
                    System.out.println("%%% MaX Waiting Time:" + MaxWaitTime / 60000 + "Min");
                    System.out.println("*********************************");

                    return link;
                } else
                    return null;
            }
        }

        return link; // Not sure what you want to return here
    }
}
```

If you are lucky enough to be on Java 8, some magic like this might be useful instead:

```
synchronized (PQueue) {
    link = PQueue.stream().filter(node -> node.waitingInQueue() > MaxWaitTime).findFirst().orElse(null);

    if (link != null)
        PQueue.remove(link);
}
```

Comment: It seems to me that there is no reason for `MaxWaitTime` to be an `Integer` instead of `int`. And making the static variables `final` wouldn’t hurt…

Comment: As that code is copied from the question maybe you should put the comment there instead?

Comment: Since you already converted two of the `Integer`s into `AtomicInteger`, you could convert the last one into `int` to get rid of all `Integer`s… However, the recommendation to make the variables `final` applies to all of them, *especially* the `AtomicInteger`s.

Comment: Btw. if you use Java 8, you can do it much simpler: `PQueue.removeIf(node -> node.waitingInQueue() > MaxWaitTime);`…